# Insertar saltos de linea mysql codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente , no le logrado que mysql 5.5 interprete los saltos de linea de un string , me lo interpreta como texto ejemplo:

NOMBRE:javier\r\nEMAIL:javier@gmail.com\r\nTELEFONO:99999999

Estoy usando codeigniter mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
$string = "NOMBRE:javier*EMAIL:javier@gmail.com*TELEFONO:99999999"
$data = array();
$data['description']  = str_replace('*','\r\n', $string);
$Where['id_user']     = $value->id_user;
$this->MainModel->editarDatos('usuarios',$data,$Where);
```

> Envio mi string por ajax con * y lo reemplazo por \r\n he intentado
>   con "\r\n", "\n\r", "\r", "\n") y "br" sin resultado me lo sigue
>   interpretando como texto

Estaré atento a sus respuestas, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

En `MySQL` siempre tu vas a ver esos detalles dentro del contenido, al igual puedes utilizar:

```
$data['description'] = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), "<br />", $string);
```

Pero jamas lo vas a ver interpretado como saldo de linea dentro de `MySQL` si no al momento de que muestras los datos de vuelta en tu sitio por medio de `php` o `ajax` depende sea el caso.